# Creating shared drive in google drive using google V3 api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a shared drive using below google api and the  [drives.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create) method.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives
```

But its giving me error as

> "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the most likely scenario is that you are using a service account to authorize your code, but you are not impersonating a Google Workspace user with domain-wide delegation.

Service accounts are basically consumer Drive accounts. They can use Drive, but they live in a space outside from your Google Workspace tenant. Only a licensed Google Workspace user can create a shared drive; service accounts can't. As a general rule, it is usually not a great idea to create Drive content as a service account.

See information about domain-wide delegation and a few code samples here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority